# .htaccess redirects only to main page ignores internal pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to get permanent redirect 'domain.com' -> 'domain.com/ru' for all pages.

```
domain.com -> domain.com/ru
domain.com/somepage -> domain.com/ru/somepage
```

Wrote the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ru/.*
RewriteRule (.*) /ru/$1 [R=302,L]
```

How it works:

```
domain.com -> domain.com/ru = Good
domain.com/somepage -> domain.com/ru = Wrong
```

How to fix .htaccess?

**UPDATE**:

.htaccess in /ru folder remains standard for Wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**UPDATE 2**

I want to get some language Wordpress installations under the root. One of them is default. But another installations also could be accessible (WP doc provide me with hardcoded default subdirectory which is not right)

```
- root folder
-- .htaccess redirects to default language
-- ru = default language installation
-- another languages
```

Comment: Your shown rule is correct. Do you also have a .htaccess in `ru/`? Also show your full .htaccess if you have more directives.

Comment: @Anubhava Good question here. I also wanted to ask the same but had to erase whole textarea when I saw your comment.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it's present - see update

Comment: [Check this tutorial for WP](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/)

Comment: .htaccess inside language folder should remains independent from language folder name